# callback called even after off?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a situation where even if I call `off` on a reference it keeps calling the callbacks?

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/31069762');

for (var n = 0; n < 1024; ++n) {
  ref.push(n)
}

ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val() > 10) {
     console.log('off') // Printed multiple times.
     ref.off();
  }
});
```

Comment: `ss` is an `Event`, so what is `ss.val().end` supposed to be?

Comment: @Barmar: It's just a value. How is it relevant to the problem?

Comment: `Event` has no `val()` method, so it should get an error when it tries to call `ss.val()`. That will prevent `segmentsRef.off()` from being done.

Comment: @Barmar: Good point. However, ss is not an `Event` it is a `Snapshot` see: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html. `segmentsRef.off()` is called.

Comment: Ahh, I thought that was jQuery `.on()`, I didn't know that Firebase also had such a method.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you change this jsbin to reproduce your problem? http://jsbin.com/hukoyenonu/edit?js,output

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: http://jsbin.com/votedaguru/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

When you call `off()` it will stop the Firebase client from firing `child_added` events for new data that comes in. It does not prevent it from firing `child_added` events for data the client already received.

You can get some interesting behavior this way. For example, your snippet:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/31069762');
ref.remove();

for (var n = 0; n < 1024; ++n) {
  ref.push(n)
}

ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  if (snapshot.val() > 10) {
     console.log('off') // Printed multiple times.
     ref.off();
  }
});
```

Will print:

```
1
2
.
.
.
11
"off"
12
"off"
.
.
.
1024
"off"
```

The data for your ref is download as "one initial packet" when you register the listener and from there on all `child_added` events are fired.

Now let's change the code around:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/31069762');
ref.remove();

ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  if (snapshot.val() > 10) {
     console.log('off') // Printed multiple times.
     ref.off();
  }
});

for (var n = 0; n < 1024; ++n) {
  ref.push(n)
}
```

So in this case we *first* register the listener and only then start pushing values. The output:

```
1
2
.
.
.
11
"off"
```

So with this ordering it stops straight away. Since we started listening for `child_added` before there was any data, the initial payload was empty and we get each child after that as a separate update.

Note that this all depends on the internals of the Firebase client and I haven't checked how it actually works there. So the "one initial packet" that I mentioned above is just how **I** visualize it.

If you really don't want to process data after `10`, there are two solutions I can think off.

1. the one you already do: keep a local "I am done" flag
2. use a `Query` to limit the data that Firebase downloads, instead of filtering client side:

   ```
   ref.orderByValue().endAt(10).on('child_added'...
   ```

   Note that `orderByValue` was introduced in version 2.2.7 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK. It took me a while to figure out why I couldn't use it in the JSBin. :-/

Comment: Ok. That should probably be documented somewhere. Especially since all other event apis guarantee that the callback is not called again after an 'off/removeEventListener'.

Comment: Agreed. We'll track how often people run in to this. So far you're the first that I'm aware off. I've definitely never noticed the behavior before today, probably because I'm pretty focused on using queries to minimize the data that reaches my clients.